# How to get top 10 videos from your channel with the views count included in the response

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

So I have a ouath web app that connects to youtube. I use the youtube analytics calls to get information like number of subscribers from my channel. But right now I try to make a top 10 videos from my channel with the views count for every video included in the response. I use this documentation:
[Top videos for subscribed or unsubscribed viewers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#top-videos-reports)

My call looks like this:

```
  $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token  . '" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-31 days')) . '&end-date=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today')). '&metrics=views&dimensions=video&sort=views"';
```

But I get an error message as a response:

```
"The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."
```

I also tried this call with YoTube data API:

```
        $videos_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&order=viewCount&type=video&access_token=' . $access_token;
```

But it provides this response:

```
 ["kind"]=>
    string(26) "youtube#searchListResponse"
    ["etag"]=>
    string(57) ""######""
    ["nextPageToken"]=>
    string(112) "#######"
    ["pageInfo"]=>
    object(stdClass)#267 (2) {
      ["totalResults"]=>
      int(1)
      ["resultsPerPage"]=>
      int(5)
    }
    ["items"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#270 (4) {
        ["kind"]=>
        string(20) "youtube#searchResult"
        ["etag"]=>
        string(57) ""#####""
        ["id"]=>
        object(stdClass)#269 (2) {
          ["kind"]=>
          string(13) "youtube#video"
          ["videoId"]=>
          string(11) "####"
        }
        ["snippet"]=>
        object(stdClass)#273 (6) {
          ["publishedAt"]=>
          string(24) "2016-09-14T14:49:49.000Z"
          ["channelId"]=>
          string(24) "#####"
          ["title"]=>
          string(12) "My Slideshow"
          ["description"]=>
          string(87) "I created this video with the YouTube Slideshow Creator (http://www.youtube.com/upload)"
```

This response provides no views count. I need for every video to get the views count as well.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Any help is welcomed! Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your youtube analytics api request is `sort` parameter. Try using value `-views` instead of `views`. You can double check the API link you provided. Also set the `max-results`

Example URL :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3Dmine&start-date=2016-05-01&end-date=2016-09-01&metrics=views&dimensions=video&max-results=10&sort=-views&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, now I have  the videos id and views count. But I need to get their titles as well. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Alan To get the video title you have to use the youtube API. `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`